# ResourceDay View with dynamic resources

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have been trying to use a fork of the fullcalendar, with a resourceDay view, from Sean Kenny: http://www.seankenny.me/blog/2014/08/11/fullcalendar-with-a-resource-day-view-v2-0-2/

I don't know if anyone has tried it, but I wanted to be able to dynamically populate the resources when date changes. I have tried setting the 'resources' value as an array, and as an URL. With an array, I get static functionality, but I was looking for something that changes the resources, so I tried using an URL:

```
resources: 'my.url'
```

I can get the page to be called, but it only gets called when the calendar is loaded, an not when the view changes. I have tried using a function, but it also only gets called once.

Has anyone had any experience with this fork, and can suggest any other approach for doing this?

I have seen other forks such as this: https://github.com/jarnokurlin/fullcalendar but since I could not find a good documentation to start from, I haven't tried it. Alternatives are welcome, if anyone knows one that works for this specific requirement.